# Displaying which tables have a string in a SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli

Is there a function or something that can print all of the tables that contain a string value in a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

You can query `information_schema`, for example:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM information_schema.columns where data_type = 'VARCHAR';
```

Just specify `data_type` that may contain strings, such as: `char`, `varchar`, `text`, `nchar`, etc. For multiple data types, add them to the query:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns where data_type IN ('CHAR', 'VARCHAR', 'TEXT', 'NCHAR');
```

Comment: but I do not know which table has the data, so what do I put as table_name

Comment: @Jake No need, use the query as it is, `table_name` and `column_name` are column names in `information_schema.columns` table.

Comment: @Jake You can check all columns in `information_schema.columns` with `SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns`.